# HTML collapsed menu doesn't close then click on link

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just checked my website via phone, and noticed that the page navigation menu does not closing then pressing any link. And i cant understand why and there is the problem. Cant find the cause of the problem... I am looking at the scrip code below to understand but...

site: www.scorpion3d.com

This is whole menu block which i have:

```
<div class="menu-block">
    <!-- Container -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Ownavigation -->
        <nav class="navbar ownavigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><span><img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo" height="64" width="64"></span>Scorpion3D</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#top" title="PRADŽIA">PRADŽIA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services-section" title="PASLAUGOS">PASLAUGOS</a></li>
                    <!-- <li><a href="#features-section" title="Features">Features</a></li> -->
                    <!-- <li><a href="#gallery-section" title="DARBAI">DARBAI</a></li> -->

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="blog.html" title="Blog" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#pricing-section" title="KAINORAŠTIS">KAINORAŠTIS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#team-section" title="APIE MUS">APIE MUS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#footer-main" title="KONTAKTAI">KONTAKTAI</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="loginpanel" class="desktop-hide">
                <div class="right" id="toggle">
                    <a id="slideit" href="#slidepanel"><i class="fo-icons fa fa-inbox"></i></a>
                    <a id="closeit" href="#slidepanel"><i class="fo-icons fa fa-close"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav><!-- Ownavigation /- -->
    </div><!-- Container /- -->
</div><!-- Menu Block /- -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct answer was to include some additional code to html or js, 
in this case I chose to include to HTML instead of:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#top" title="PRADŽIA">PRADŽIA</a></li>
```

changed to all links like per example:

```
<a href="#top" title="PRADŽIA" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">PRADŽIA</a></li>
```

Now mobile version menu close instantly then any link in the menu pressed.
don't forget to add after menu end single div:

```
<div class="collapse" id="navbar"></div>
```

Comment: but this mess up desktop view, i mean the navbar for desktop will try to close it up as well, so it is flickering... so if anyone will find better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The drop down menu opens and closes properly on a resized monitor on my side. Try clear your cache. It could be that or possibly you have linked your bootstrap and jquery files wrong.

Include your jquery file first, then bootstrap both in the footer. Ensure nothing is in the header, or that duplicates are present.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Cleared the cashe, moved :
 <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.youtube.min.js"></script>
to the footer area, then checked the page, it crashed not loading page at all, then i've tried to move one by one. so <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script> cannot be at the bottom as they not loading the page. reverted changes back..

Comment: maybe i've explained not well. Sorry for my english. I mean that then you open menu on resized for example display for mobile device. You can see the button of menu. then u pressing the button it opens. It is good, working, but then presing the link for example "Paslaugos" mean services it should close the menu and go to "paslaugos" ancor point. but the issue is that  menu do not close. it should shrink down.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong path for jquery.min.js (404).
Make sure the script jquery.min.js is in the assets/js folder.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. Cheked and u are right jquery.min.js was missing to load renamed from jquery-1.12.4.min.js to jquery.min.js so now they both loaded. but still not fixing the problem.

Comment: @cursedmonk You haven't fixed it. It still says 404 not found for jquery.min.js

Comment: I've fixed locally currently, not loading it to the server ( as once i've crashed all the site ) so all changes firstly doing locally, after then issues resolved and site functional i am updating in the server.

Comment: Ok tell us when it's on your server then we can take a look at your problem if it's not solved.

Comment: I think you forgot to add the file bootstrap.css in your head. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />`